# How to properly catch RuntimeExceptions from Executors?

Tags: java, concurrency, executor, runtimeexception

Say that I have the following code:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(myRunnable);
```

Now, if `myRunnable` throws a `RuntimeExcpetion`, how can I catch it? One way would be to supply my own `ThreadFactory` implementation to `newSingleThreadExecutor()` and set custom `uncaughtExceptionHandler`s for the `Thread`s that come out of it. Another way would be to wrap `myRunnable` to a local (anonymous) `Runnable` that contains a try-catch -block. Maybe there are other similar workarounds too. But... somehow this feels dirty, I feel that it shouldn't be this complicated. Is there a clean solution?

Comment: Honestly I question the sense of catching an exception thrown in a *different* thread. Does the current thread have to `join` the thread and wait for the exception to be thrown? You didn't cover that in the question.

Comment: @BalusC: Marshalling an exception from a worker thread back onto a calling thread is a common requirement of many applications.  For example, a UI application may invoke a SwingWorker thread to do some background processing.  If the processing fails the exception needs to be passed back to the Event Dispatch thread.

Comment: It's a common requirement. Thread 1 generates some work, executes it via thread 2, but needs to understand if it's succeeded or not (i.e. thrown an exception). The Executor framework helps you with this.

Comment: Umm, actually I hadn't thought about it this far. I was just curious about how, in general, to approach this problem. But people seem to have something cool to say about `submit()` and `Future` below :-)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The clean workaround is to use `ExecutorService.submit()` instead of `execute()`. This returns you a `Future` which you can use to retrieve the result or exception of the task:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    throw new RuntimeException("foo");
  }
};

Future<?> future = executor.submit(task);
try {
  future.get();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  Exception rootException = e.getCause();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks exactly as the way it's *intended* to be. Clean.

Comment: Also, you may want to use `Callable` rather than `Runnable`, then your task can throw checked exceptions as well as unchecked.

Comment: getCause returns a Throwable not an exception in 1.6 and 1.7

Comment: The problem is that future.get() is blocking, so if you want to be able to run your task asynchronously it's not OK

Comment: As commented by @Loic, this solution makes no use as it defeats the whole purpose of using Executors in the first place.

Comment: @Loic @m0skit0 I don't see the problem. Submit multiple jobs and store their futures (this step behaves like *fork*), after all jobs were submitted, call `get` on the stored futures (if you `get` all futures, this step behaves like a *join*). Drawback: You cannot catch exceptions at the time they were thrown. You have  to wait until all jobs terminated (in the worst case). However, [OP only cared about *how*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687977/how-to-properly-catch-runtimeexceptions-from-executors#comment1562723_1687977) but not *when* to catch exceptions.

Answer (score 11):

Decorate the runnable in another runnable which catches the runtime exceptions and handles them:

```
public class REHandler implements Runnable {
    Runnable delegate;
    public REHandler (Runnable delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
    public void run () {
        try {
            delegate.run ();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            ... your fancy error handling here ...
        }
    }
}

executor.execute(new REHandler (myRunnable));
```

Answer (score 9):

Why not call [`ExecutorService#submit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29), get the [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) back and then handle possible exceptions yourself when calling [`Future#get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29) ?

Answer (score 6):

skaffman is correct in that using `submit` is the cleanest approach.  An alternative approach is to subclass [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and override `afterExecute(Runnable, Throwable)`.  If you follow this approach **be sure to call `execute(Runnable)`** rather than `submit(Runnable)` or `afterExecute` will not be invoked.

Per the API description:

> Method invoked upon completion of
>   execution of the given Runnable. This
>   method is invoked by the thread that
>   executed the task. If non-null, the
>   Throwable is the uncaught
>   **`RuntimeException`**  or **`Error`** that caused
>   execution to terminate abruptly.
>
> Note: When actions are enclosed in
>   tasks (such as FutureTask) either
>   explicitly or via methods such as
>   submit, these task objects catch and
>   maintain computational exceptions, and
>   so they do not cause abrupt
>   termination, and the internal
>   exceptions are **not passed to this
>   method**.

Answer (score 2):

a task(`Callable` or `Runnable`) submitted to `ThreadPoolExecutors` will be convert to a `FuturnTask`, contains a prop named **`callable`** equals the task you submit. FuturnTask has its own `run` method as follows. All exception or throwable throwed in `c.call()` will be catched and put into a prop named `outcome`. When calling FuturnTask's `get` method, `outcome` will be throwed

FuturnTask.run From Jdk1.8 Source Code

```
public void run() {
        ...
        try {
            Callable<V> c = callable;
            if (c != null && state == NEW) {
                V result;
                boolean ran;
                try {
                    result = c.call();
                    ran = true;
                } catch (Throwable ex) {
                    result = null;
                    ran = false;
                    // save ex into `outcome` prop
                    setException(ex);
                }
                if (ran)
                    set(result);
            }
        }
        ...
    }
```

if you want catch the exception :

    1. skaffman's answer
    2. overwrite `afterExecute` when you new a ThreadPoolExecutor

```
        @Override
        protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
            super.afterExecute(r, t);
            Throwable cause = null;
            if (t == null && r instanceof Future) {
                try {
                    ((Future<?>) r).get();
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    cause = e;
                }
            } else if (t != null) {
                cause = t;
            }
            if (cause != null) {
                // log error
            }
        }
```