# Exception handling in ThreadPools

Tags: java, exception, threadpool

I have a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor that seems to be eating Exceptions.  I want my executor service to notify me if a submitted Runnable throws an exception.

For example, I'd like the code below to at the very least print the IndexArrayOutOfBoundsException's stackTrace

```
threadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(
  new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      int[] array = new array[0];
      array[42] = 5;
    }
  },
  1000,
  1500L,
  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

As a side question.  Is there a way to write a general try catch block for a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?

//////////END OF ORIGINAL QUESTION //////////////

As suggested the following Decorator works well.

```
public class CatcherTask implements Runnable{

    Runnable runMe;

    public CatcherTask(Runnable runMe) {
        this.runMe = runMe;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            runMe.run();
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent question. I wonder why only few people run into this.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687977/how-to-properly-catch-runtimeexceptions-from-executors

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I wrote a small [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20120213060953/https://www.cosmocode.de/en/blog/schoenborn/2009-12/17-uncaught-exceptions-in-scheduled-tasks) about this problem a while ago. You have two options:

1. Use the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875739/exception-handling-in-threadpools/3875807#3875807) provided by Colin Herbert or
2. use a modified version of Mark Peters [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875739/exception-handling-in-threadpools/3875784#3875784) but instead of assigning a `UncaughtExceptionHandler` you wrap each submitted runnable into a runnable of your own which executes (calls `run`) the real runnable inside a try-catch-block.

**EDIT**
As pointed out by Mark, it's important to wrap the `Runnable` passed to `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of the one passed to the `ThreadFactory`.

Comment: Alright I confirmed it and deleted my answer.  Thanks!  Feel free to modify your step 2 to go into details.

Comment: Actually I tried your #2 and couldn't get it to work.  The exception was caught well above my try/catch block in the delegating Runnable, so this seems to succumb to the same problem as the UncaughtExceptionHandler.

Comment: I just accepted this -- But Mark is saying Decorating the submitted tasks with a try/catch isn't ....I'm gonna try this out.

Comment: @Ivan: I'm not saying that wouldn't work.  Willi seemed at first (through his reference to my suggestion) to be suggesting that you wrap the Runnable submitted to `ThreadFactory.newThread(Runnable)` with a Runnable that catches the exception.  That won't work.  Wrapping each Runnable *submitted* to the executor *will* work but has little to do with my suggestions, so that link should probably be removed for clarity.

Comment: Here's an article on exception-handling in threaded code, including `Future` and `ExecutorService`: http://literatejava.com/threading/silent-thread-death-unhandled-exceptions/

Comment: This is a very good catch. I was quite intrigued by this behaviour, and I am glad I finally found someone else who also encountered this. I wonder why this behaviour exists...

Answer (score 13):

**Warning**: This method is not applicable to **scheduled** thread pool executors.  This answer has been undeleted for its relevance to other thread pool executors.  See [Willi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875739/exception-handling-in-threadpools/3875968#3875968).

Override the `ThreadFactory` to give Threads an UncaughtExceptionHandler:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ThreadPoolExecutor...;

exec.setThreadFactory(new ExceptionCatchingThreadFactory(exec.getThreadFactory()));
//go on to submit tasks...


private static class ExceptionCatchingThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    private final ThreadFactory delegate;

    private ExceptionCatchingThreadFactory(ThreadFactory delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public Thread newThread(final Runnable r) {
        Thread t = delegate.newThread(r);
        t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //replace with your handling logic.
            }
        });
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: `UncaughExceptionHandler` does not work with scheduled runnables.

Comment: @Willi: Let me verify and then I'll delete it if I confirm.

Comment: Undeleting since it still seems to be useful for non-scheduled thread pool executors.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `get()` method from the `Future` you're getting by calling `scheduleAtFixedRate()`. It will throw an `ExecutionException` if an exeception occurred during the thread execution.

Comment: How does that work for subsequent invocations?  e.g. how do you get a future for the second invocation, after the first has returned successfully?

Comment: @Mark If one execution failed, there will be no second (or third, ...) execution. Copied from the original javadoc: *If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed.*

Comment: @Willi: Then I guess I'm confused about the OP's statement "seems to be eating Exceptions..." if it's only ever run once.

Comment: @Mark -- The problem I was having is that a repeating Scheduled task was throwing an exception -- then the thread executing that task just died with no indication that a thread in my thread pool encountered a problem.

Comment: @Mark Good point. Maybe he meant one Exception from multiple runs?

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` from the [Spring Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html), which exposes a method  to set an error handler and does all the wrapping for you. The default behavior depends on the type of task:

*If the provided `ErrorHandler` is not null, it will be used. Otherwise, repeating tasks will have errors suppressed by default whereas one-shot tasks will have errors propagated by default since those errors may be expected through the returned `Future`. In both cases, the errors will be logged.*

If you only want to use the wrapping part and not the `TaskScheduler` you can use

```
TaskUtils.decorateTaskWithErrorHandler(task, errorHandler, isRepeatingTask)
```

which the `TaskScheduler` uses internally.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and override the [afterExecute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Throwable)) method to handle exceptions and errors for any kind of Runnable that you submit.

Answer (score -1):

Consider adding a static event in your *ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor* class that any of your tasks can call if an exception is thrown.  That way, you can leverage that event to capture and handle the exceptions that occur within your threads.